# How will I able to upload *.app to Appstore not via Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, go, app-store, app-store-connect

I have application for iOS created on Go language, I compiled it to .app file. Can anyone tell me what should I do to:

1. Load application to my iPhone
2. Load application to iTunes connect (I loaded another via Xcode, but there are no objective c or swift code here to do so)

PS: I have valid developer account, able to create any certificates that will need. Versions: XCode 7.2, iOS 9.2

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Sorry,as I konw,you can't load an .app to your iPhone(.ipa OK).

Comment: 2.You should make out info of app first.

Answer (score 2):

For submission part there is Apple tool called Application Loader. It is a part of Xcode, but I think can still be downloaded separately. It can deliver app to App Store without having to use Xcode Organiser interface.

You need to deliver your app as .ipa file. If your .app is properly signed and contains a valid .mobileprovision (which is a different question), all you need to do is to create a new folder named "Payload", put copy your .app into ito it. Then you can rename the .zip file to .ipa and upload it using Application loader.